Is it better to bribe the game or just play again?
My wife is playing a game which has a mini card game inside, and I'm curious the picking the best way to play it. Here are the rules of that card game:

It has 5 rounds max. Each round they show you 3 cards face down. One
of them is Death. Two others are Sun. You have to pick one.
If you pick Death, the game is over, you got nothing.
If you pick Sun, you get a random prize of this round. And you're
allowed to play one more round. (Remember, the max is 5). But you're not obliged. You can stop right here and get this prize.
If you picked Death, you're also allowed to bribe the game and get Sun
instead along with the ability to play one more round. If will cost
you 25, 50, 100, 200 or 400 coins depending on the round (1st, 2nd,
and so on).
The first game of the day is free. Others are cost you 25 coins to
start.

Let's assume that the game is fair, and the probability of getting Death is 1/3.
Also, let's ignore the prizes in total. In reality it's important what the prize you get 'cause it may force you to stop earlier.
The question I'm trying to answer is “Is it even worth to bribe the game on any round? If yes, then on which rounds?”
Here's my solution.
First, we calculate the probability of winning on every round with progressing through them. Since you can not get Death and Sun at the same time, here it is:
$$P_1 = \frac{2}{3} \approx 66.7\% \\P_2 = (\frac{2}{3})^2 \approx 44.4\% \\P_3 = (\frac{2}{3})^3 \approx 29.6\% \\P_4 = (\frac{2}{3})^4 \approx 19.8\% \\P_5 = (\frac{2}{3})^5 \approx 13.2\% $$
Now, let's assume you get Death on the first round. Should you bribe the game for 25 coins and get Sun instead? Or you'd better to start again for the same 25 coins?
As far as I understand, to answer this question we need to calculate the number of games we have to play to be sure to win on the first round at least once. To do this, we can not simply $\lceil\frac {100\%}{P_n}\rceil$, because the events we're dealing with are not mutually exclusive.
But what should we do instead? How to properly calculate that number of games? I read the Wiki article I linked above, but not sure I got the point.
To sum up, I need help with these questions:

Is it worth to bribe the game on any of the rounds? Why? If there is no exact answer, is there any other? (e.g. “It's 99% not worth to bribe on round N”)

Am I right when think that there is no such thing as “be sure to win on the N round at least once”, because we're dealing with probability, and it can not be 100% in these cases?



Edit: There are game examples and questions they rise.
GAME 1 (free because it's the first of the day)

Round 1: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 1st, got Sun: [S] [2] [3]
Decided to get the prize. Game over.


GAME 2 (25 coins)

Round 1: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 2nd, got Death: [1] [D] [3]
Decided to bribe the game for 25 coins.
Got Sun instead: [1] [2] [S]
Decided to play next round.

Round 2: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 3rd, got Sun: [1] [2] [S]
Decided to play next round.

Round 3: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 3rd, got Sun: [1] [2] [S]
Decided to play next round.

Round 4: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 2nd, got Death: [1] [D] [3]
Decided to bribe the game for 200 coins.
Got Sun instead: [S] [2] [3]
Decided to get the prize. Game over.


GAME 3 (25 coins)

Round 1: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 1st, got Sun: [S] [2] [3]
Decided to play next round.

Round 2: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 3rd, got Death: [1] [2] [D]
Decided to give up. Got nothing. Game over. 


GAME 4 (25 coins)

Round 1: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 3rd, got Sun: [1] [2] [S]
Decided to play next round.

Round 2: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 2nd, got Death: [1] [D] [3]
Decided to bribe the game for 50 coins.

Round 3: [1] [2] [3]
Picked 2nd, got Death: [1] [D] [3]
Decided to give up. Got nothing. Game over. 

There are the questions to illustrate the problem:

I bribed the Game 2 on the 4th round for 200 coins. Was it worth it? Or it was better to play 8 games more instead (because each game costs 25 coins).

I did not bribe the Game 3 on the 2nd round for 50 coins. Instead I started the Game 4 for 25 coins. Was this a correct decision from the perspective of win probability?

Again, I did not bribe the Game 4 on the 3nd round for 100 coins. Was it wrong?


Please, note: The prize itself does not matter along with its cost. What matters is the round of the game where the prize is got. Let's assume that prize of Nth round is N times cooler than the prize of the 1st level. In other words, “weight” of the prize equals to the number of the round where this prize is got.
I did not think that the cost of prizes was important when I created this question. But if the problem is not possible to solve without additional data like this, please let me know.

I don't think there is enough information here. What's the prize?  If it is uncertain, what's the distribution?  If the maximum prize is $2$, you shouldn't pay $25$ for a chance at it.  If the maximal prize is $10^8$, then it may make sense to pay up.   Once the prize is clarified, this should be a simple matter of looking at expected value (assuming your goal is to maximize expected value).

@lulu, maybe I was not clear enough. The prize itself along with its cost does not matter. What does matter is the fact of getting the prize. You can get the prize when you pick a Sun card. Or you can play the next round and try your luck there. My goal is to maximize the ability to get prizes with lowest amount of coins. That's why I'm asking whether it's worth to bribe or to play again.

@lulu, just to clarify: I can rewrite the question, I just do not understand what exactly I should rewrite. If I add an example of the game (e.g. I picked this card, picked that card, etc), will it help?

@lulu, ah, I probably got your point! Sorry for me being a Slowpoke. I edited the question and added the note about prize cost. Is it possible to solve it right now? Or I need to find a way to convert prizes to coins?

I don't understand.  If my only goal is to get a prize, then I should just keep paying until I win.  Why not? Stopping just guarantees failure

I assumed that you wanted to limit your spending, but in order to understand that we need more information

Interestingly, the answer will depend on what you are trying to maximize. For example, if the prize for the final round is $1$ billion coins, then you might not care about bribing each step of the way since it will be faster overall (ie making more money over time) to just pay the fee and move on. However, if you are trying to minimize your expected cost (ie spend the least amount of coins to win round $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$) then it only sometimes makes sense to bribe your way to victory. Ignoring the first game being free since the question is about restarting versus bribing, I'll show that it is advantageous to bribe if you lose in round $1$, it doesn't matter if you bribe  if you lose in round $2$ (cost wise, time wise I would still say bribe), and you shouldn't bribe if you lose in later rounds. Now, a key insight is that if winning round $k$ also requires winning round $k-1$. That is, if there is a strategy to minimize the expected cost to win round $k-1$, then that strategy should also be used to get to round $k$. This implies that we can look at each round separately and use the expected cost of winning the previous round (assuming optimal play) to calculate the expected cost (assuming optimal play) of winning the next round.
Round 1
Suppose you want to win round $1$, there are $2$ strategies: Either you will bribe after round $1$, or you will not (assuming you pulled the death card). If you don't bribe, the expected cost to win is
$$25+25\cdot \frac{1}{3}+25\cdot \frac{1}{3^2}+...=25\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3^k}=25\cdot \frac{3}{2}=37.5$$
If you bribe after pulling the death card, your expected cost is
$$25+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 25=25\cdot \frac{4}{3}=\frac{100}{3}=33.333...$$
So it makes sense to bribe your way forward if you pull the death card in round $1$.
Round 2
The math above can be repeated, except this time the bribe is $50$ and the 'buy-in' is the previous rounds expected cost of $\frac{100}{3}$. If you don't bribe if you pull the death card in round $2$ you get an expected cost of
$$\frac{100}{3}+\frac{100}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{100}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3^2}+...=\frac{100}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{2}=50$$
If you do bribe after pulling a death card in round $2$ you have an expected cost of
$$\frac{100}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 50=\frac{150}{3}=50$$
Either way, your expected cost is $50$. Since I can't imagine a scenario where you would rather take more time than less time, I'm going to say it is advantageous to bribe in round $2$.
Remaining rounds
It should now be obvious what to do. Denote $C_{k-1}$ to be the expected cost to win round $k-1$ and $B_k$ to be the bribe for round $k$. Then $C_k$ is given by
$$C_k=\min\left\{\frac{3}{2}C_{k-1},C_{k-1}+\frac{1}{3}B_k\right\}$$
where $\frac{3}{2}C_{k-1}$ corresponds to not bribing upon pulling the death card and $C_{k-1}+\frac{1}{3}B_k$ corresponds to bribing after pulling the death card. These numbers are easily calculated
$$C_3=75$$
$$C_4=\frac{225}{2}=112.5$$
$$C_5=\frac{675}{4}=168.75$$
and in each round it is more efficient to start over rather than bribing.
In total, the expected costs to win any particular round (assuming you bribe in round $1$ and don't bribe in rounds $3,4,5$) are given by
$$\left[\frac{100}{3},50,75,\frac{225}{2},\frac{675}{4}\right]$$
$$[33.33...,50,75,112.5,168.75]$$
This also give you an idea about what to do to maximize expected value dependent on the possible prizes. If the prize for round $5$ is $200$ coins, then it makes sense to keep playing. However, if the prize is $150$, then it wouldn't make sense to play for round $5$. This can lead to some interesting situations: suppose the prizes are given by $[0,25,75,125,175]$. From the previous work, we know that rounds $1-3$ give non-positive expected value while rounds $4-5$ have positive expected value. However, round $4$ has a greater expected value than round $5$. Thus, the strategy for these prizes is to play for round $4$ and don't bother with round $5$.

Let me start by saying that I agree with the comments above and, for me, it doesn't make much sense to say whether bribing is worth if we don't have a way to compare prize and cost. So, let's see how this may go if we can give a coin value to the prize.
For now, let's just focus on a single game. Let $A(n)$ denote the assets (i.e., coins and prizes) we have after round $n$. We say that an $n$-round game is worth playing if
$$
\mathbb{E}[A(n)] > A(0)
$$
that is if the value of our assets after $n$ rounds is expected to be larger than what we have before starting.
In order to compute $\mathbb{E}[A(n)]$, let $B(n)$ denote the assets we have before round $n$. Note that $B(n)$ may differ from $A(n-1)$, i.e. the assets after round $n-1$, since $B(n)$ is evaluated after we take the decision to play again and, specifically,

$B(n) = A(n-1)$ if we won round $n-1$;
$B(n) = A(n-1) - C(n-1)$ if we won lost $n-1$, where $C(n-1)$ is the cost of the bribe.

Now, if we let $S(n)$ be the price value for round $n$, we can rewrite the above equations without referencing $A(n-1)$:

$B(n)=B(n-1) + S(n-1)$ if we won round $n-1$;
$B(n)=B(n-1) - C(n-1)$ if we lost round $n-1$.

Let $G(n)\in\{\text{Sun}, \text{Death}\}$ denote the outcome of round $n$, with $p=\Pr[G(n)=\text{Sun}]=2/3$. Then, we have the following easy recursion for $\mathbb{E}[B(n)]$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[B(n)] &= \mathbb{E}[B(n)|G(n-1)=\text{Sun}]p + \mathbb{E}[B(n)|G(n-1)=\text{Death}](1-p) \\
&=\mathbb{E}[B(n-1)+S(n-1)]p + \mathbb{E}[B(n-1)-C(n-1)](1-p) \\
&=\mathbb{E}[B(n-1)]+S(n-1)p - C(n-1)(1-p) \\
&=B(1)+p\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S(k) - (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C(k)
\end{align}
where we used the fact that $B(1)$ is deterministic (recall that we are focusing on only one game, and $B(1)=A(0)$ or $B(1)=A(0)-25$).
It is straightforward now to express the expected amount of assets after the $n$-th round:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[A(n)] &= \mathbb{E}[A(n)|G(n)=\text{Sun}]p + \mathbb{E}[A(n)|G(n)=\text{Death}](1-p) \\
&=\mathbb{E}[B(n)+S(n)]p + \mathbb{E}[B(n)](1-p) \\
&=\mathbb{E}[B(n)]+S(n)p \\
&=B(1)+p\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(k) - (1-p)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C(k).
\end{align}
Now we can answer to our original question: is an $n$-round game worth playing? Only if $\mathbb{E}[A(n)] > A(0)$, or, from the prize point of view, only if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(k) > \frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C(k)+\frac{1}{p}F(0)
$$
where $F(0)=A(0)-B(1)$ is the entry fee.
Assume now that $\mathbb{E}[A(1)] < A(0)$, is it worth entering the game anyway? Only if $\mathbb{E}[A(n)] > A(0)$ for at least one $n=2,\dots 5$ (for example, prize $S(5)$ may be so big that we don't care if we have to bribe all the way to the 5th round).
Note, however, that we can do even better, since the game allows us to adapt the strategy as we go along. Indeed, once we played round $l$ we know $A(l)=a_l$ and $B(l+1)=b_{l+1}$ and we can compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[A(n)|B(l+1)=b_{l+1}] = b_{l+1}+p\sum_{k=l+1}^{n}S(k) - (1-p)\sum_{k=l+1}^{n-1}C(k).
$$
It's worth going on only if $\mathbb{E}[A(n)|B(l+1)=b_{l+1}] > a_l$ for some $n=l+1, l+2, \dots$
Multiple games
If we play multiple games and we consider the total reward (as opposed to consider each game separately), the main idea still holds, but the details become more complicated since the number of strategies to compare doesn't depend only on the number of rounds, but also on whether we follow with the same game or we switch game, as well as the round at which we change game.
A suboptimal approach would be to continue on the current game while it is convenient, according to the above strategy. Once the game is over (or we decide to drop), we are left with assets that amount to $a_{\text{previous}}$. Then, we evaluate whether a second game is worth playing using again the strategy above, but setting $A(0)=a_{\text{previous}}$.
